# Subsetting Table in R when IDs are non-unique and Values match

Tags: r, group-by, subset

I have a dataframe that contains IDs and a value. I want to subset this dataframe so that it only keeps rows that contain non-unique ID (more than 1 occurrence in the table), while the value for that ID is also the same.

For Example:

DF:

```
ID  Value
1     A
1     A
1     B
2     C
3     B
3     B
4     A
4     C
```

I want the Subset to look like:

```
ID   Value
1      A
1      A
3      B
3      B
```

I've tried to first create subsets of the table to eliminate non-unique IDs:

```
Unique <- subset(df, df$ID %in% names(which(table(df$ID) >1)))
```

However when I then try and subset this table again where the value is the same for the ID, I get stuck. Wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(ID, Value) %>%  mutate(N=n()) %>% filter(N > 1) %>% select(-N) %>% ungroup()` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)    

df %>% group_by(ID, Value) %>% 
           filter(n() >= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` + `ave`

```
> subset(df, ave(ID, ID, Value, FUN = length) > 1)
  ID Value
1  1     A
2  1     A
5  3     B
6  3     B
```

Answer (score 0):

With `table` and `subset`

```
subset(df, paste(ID, Value) %in% names(which(table(paste(ID, Value)) > 1)))
```

-output

```
  ID Value
1  1     A
2  1     A
5  3     B
6  3     B
```